# Review the batch script to speedup actions

Tags: string, directory, path, nested-loops, subdirectory

Please Go through the script, it is working fine but It is processing folders a bit slow it is basically due to inner loop which is not breaking after action done. For example when 'Rename_Move_to_Matched_Folder_Path' switch is enabled the script is trying to find matched even when a match already found and moved.

2nd I am getting
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.

after following echoes
___ R E N A M I N G ___ "path" Folder will Moved After this Renaming.
___ M O V I N G ___ "path" FOLDER

I tried putting labels / flags but nothing worked so far.

```
@echo off`
REM Set the root folder where the folders to modify reside.
set "rootFolder=%CD%"

REM Set the variable to empty for actual execution. Put "REM" to enable Test Run.
set "test_Run=REM"

REM Folders to Modify :: Process the Source Folders supposed to Modify.
set "folderToModify_Open="
set "folderToModify_Close=_"

REM Folders to Match :: Process the Folders to Search in Sub Folder where Source Folder is supposed to move.
set "FolderToMatch_Open="
set "FolderToMatch_Close=#"

REM Define Actions, Set any one action at a time to avoid conflicts
::set "action_Switch=Rename_with_prefix_suffix"
::set "Rename_Prefix=zz_"
::set "Rename_Suffix=_Renamed"
REM Rename folderToModify as FolderToMatch with defined Suffix Keep folders at its current location. Remove :: from beginning to enable this action.
::set "action_Switch=Rename_as_Matched"
::set "Rename_Suffix=_Matched"

REM Rename with Rename_Suffix and move to matched folder location. Remove :: from beginning to enable this action.
::set "action_Switch=Rename_Move_within_Matched_Folder"
::set "Rename_Suffix=_Moved"

REM Rename with Rename_Suffix and move to matched folder Path and not within matched folder. Remove :: from beginning to enable this action.
set "action_Switch=Rename_Move_to_Matched_Folder_Path"
set "Rename_Suffix=_Moved"

REM Simply moved to matched folder location without renaming. Remove :: from beginning to enable this action.
::set "action_Switch=move_to_Matched_Folder_Path"

REM Simply merge with matched folder to its location without renaming. Remove :: from beginning to enable this action.
::set "action_Switch=Merge_with_matched"

REM Default Folder for unmatched files
set "defaultFolder=[__Unmatched__]"
set "default_Folder_Switch=REM"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Searching for folders to modify in %CD%...
echo.

REM Iterate through all folders
for /d /r "%rootFolder%" %%f in (*%folderToModify_Close%*) do (
    set "folderToModifyName=%%~nxf"
    echo Found folder to modify: "%%~nxf"

    REM Extract the substring between the delimiters
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=%folderToModify_Open%%folderToModify_Close%" %%A in ("!folderToModifyName!") do set "folderToModifyString=%%A"
    echo Extracted string from folder to modify: "!folderToModifyString!"

    REM Search for matching folders in the destination folder and its subdirectories
    set "folderMatched=false"
    for /d /r "%rootFolder%" %%F in (*%folderToMatch_Close%*) do (
        set "matchedFolderName=%%~fF"
        echo Processing Folders to Match: "%%~fF"
        REM Extract the substring between the delimiters from folders in the destination folder
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=%FolderToMatch_Open%%FolderToMatch_Close%" %%B in ("%%~nxF") do set "matchFolderString=%%B"
        REM enable this echo only while debug, else it will echo all folder being searched, which may be a long list.
        echo Extracted String [ !matchFolderString! ] from Matched Folder [ %%~nxF ] Path [%%~fF]
        

        REM Compare the extracted strings (case-insensitive) between Folder to Modify and Folders in the destination folder
        if /i "!matchFolderString!"=="!folderToModifyString!" (
            if "!action_Switch!"=="Merge_with_matched" (
            
                echo ___ M E R G I N G ___ "%%f" with "%%F" folder
                %test_Run% move "%%f\*" "%%F"
                echo ___ R E M O V I N G ___ "%%f" folder
                %test_Run% rd "%%f"
            
            ) else if "!action_Switch!"=="move_to_Matched_Folder_Path" (            
                echo ___ M O V I N G ___ "%%f" to "%%~dpF" location
                %test_Run% move "%%f" "%%~dpF"
                
            
            ) else if "!action_Switch!"=="Rename_with_prefix_suffix" (
                echo ___ R E N A M I N G ___ "%%f" to "%Rename_Prefix%!folderToModifyString!%Rename_Suffix%"
                %test_Run% ren "%%f" "%Rename_Prefix%!folderToModifyString!%Rename_Suffix%"
                
            ) else if "!action_Switch!"=="Rename_as_Matched" (
                echo ___ R E N A M I N G ___ "%%f" to "%%~nF%Rename_Suffix%"
                %test_Run% ren "%%f" "%%~nF%Rename_Suffix%"
                
            ) else if "!action_Switch!"=="Rename_Move_within_Matched_Folder" (               
                echo ___ R E N A M I N G ___ "%%f" to "%%~nF%Rename_Suffix%" Folder will Moved After this Renaming.
                %test_Run% ren "%%f" "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!"
                echo ___ M O V I N G ___ "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!" IN "!matchedFolderName!\" FOLDER
                %test_Run% move "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!" "!matchedFolderName!\"
                
            ) else if "!action_Switch!"=="Rename_Move_to_Matched_Folder_Path" (
                REM result are same as 2nd code block.
                echo ___ R E N A M I N G ___ "%%f" to "%%~nF%Rename_Suffix%" Folder will Moved After this Renaming.
                %test_Run% ren "%%f" "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!"
                echo ___ M O V I N G ___ "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!" IN "%%~dpF" FOLDER              
                %test_Run% move "%%~nF!Rename_Suffix!" "%%~dpF"
                
                REM working fine, prompting error for matched folder found in root folder, which is obvious, we can use this.
                ::echo ___ M O V I N G ___ "%%f" to "%%~dpF" location
                ::%test_Run% move "%%f" "%%~dpF"    REM Changed destination to "%%~dpF" (path of folderToMatch)
                ::echo ___ R E N A M I N G ___ "%%~dpF%%~nxf" to "%%~nxf%Rename_Suffix%"
                ::%test_Run% ren "%%~dpF%%~nxf" "%%~nxf%Rename_Suffix%"
            
                
                
            )
            set "folderMatched=true"
        )
    )

    if not "!folderMatched!"=="true" (
        echo ___ NO ACTION ___ No matching folder found for "%%f"
        
        REM Create the default folder if it doesn't exist
        %default_Folder_Switch% if not exist "%rootFolder%\%defaultFolder%" mkdir "%rootFolder%\%defaultFolder%"
        %default_Folder_Switch% move "%%f" "%rootFolder%\%defaultFolder%"
        %default_Folder_Switch% echo [ "%%f" ] MOVED TO [ %rootFolder%\%defaultFolder% ]                 
        echo.       
    )

    echo.
)

echo.
endlocal
pause
```

`